# Jquery to Vanilla js, fontsize auto

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't convert to Vanilla js, sorry for the clumsy english))
need to change the font size from the external block.

```js
fontsize = function () {
    var fontSize = $("#container").width() * 0.10; // 10% of container width
    $("#container h1").css('font-size', fontSize);
};
$(window).resize(fontsize);
$(document).ready(fontsize);
```

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#container {
    height:75%;
    width:75%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <h1>This is my text</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What part can't you convert? What did you attempt?

Comment: fontsize = function () {
    var fontSize = $("#container").width() * 0.10; // 10% of container width
    $("#container h1").css('font-size', fontSize);
};
$(window).resize(fontsize);
$(document).ready(fontsize);

i'm not good at js i'm new
this is difficult for me
>> .width() * 0.10;
>> .resize

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style | https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without JS at all

```css
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#container {
    height:75%;
    width:75%;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    padding:1%;
}
#container h1 {
    font-size: 7.5vw /* 100vw = 100%. then 75% of container and 10% font size will be 7.5 */
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <h1>This is my text</h1>
</div>
```